# How to select rows that match two columns with OR in postgresql and return the 5 unique rows with the highest timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm building an SMS application and so the user might exchange multiple messages with many different numbers but for the overview screen only the latest message with the latest timestamp should show and the 5 latest conversations. So, select all rows that match the from or to fields and among those, return the row with the highest timestamp, and then return the 5 rows with the highest timestamps. How can I accomplish this with the below query?

```
      .createQueryBuilder('sms')
      .where({
        from: userphoneNumber OR
        to: userphonenumber
      })
      .distinct() should return the most recent createdAt field among matching rows
      .orderBy('createdAt') 
      .limit(5 for paging)
      .getRawMany()
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your previous question. Please delete it and instead add the requested information (better explanation of the relevant columns) to that question.